# The getView() method of custom ArrayAdapter is not getting called

Tags: android, adapter, android-arrayadapter

I am very new to android development. I am trying to a build an application. I am using ArrayAdapter for list view but ArrayAdapter getView() method is not called.

I put a debugger inside ArrayAdapter constructor and checked, I am getting list size of 16 but getView() method is not called.

Here is my code for ArrayAdapter.

```
public class Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {

    private List<Item> list;
    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public Adapter(Context context, int resource, List<Item> list) {
        super(context, resource, list);
        this.list = list;
        this.context = context;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.section_list, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.text = convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        final Item item = getItem(position);

        holder.text.setText(item.getTitle());



        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if (this.list != null && this.list.size() > 0) {
            return this.list.size();
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        private TextView text;
    }
}
```

How I am calling adapter:

```
 adapter = new Adapter(getContext(), R.layout.section_list, listItem);
 notificationListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Here is my Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="MAXOFEN is PEACHES"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my list item in a fragment:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout

       android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout

           android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/shadow"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="visible">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="12dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:text="@string/notifications"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:text="@string/see_all"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@color/hrLine" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/userNameLl"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="12dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/danger_alert_copy" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/userName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:text="harsh" />


            </LinearLayout>

            <com.knowyourmeds.utils.ExpandableHeightListView
                android:id="@+id/list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:divider="@null"
                android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```

How I am generating List:

```
Item item;
List<Item> listItem = new ArrayList<>();
item = new Item(1l,null,"body","title");
listItem.add(item);

item = new Item(2l,null,"body 1","title 1");
listItem.add(item);

item = new Item(3l,null,"body 2","title 2");
listItem.add(item);

item = new Item(5l,null,"body 3","title 3");
listItem.add(item);
```

Let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: Post your layout!

Comment: Check you Array List Size , if  should have at least one element

Comment: @MeosCoder please check updated question

Comment: @ChetanJoshi yes I put a debugger and checked list size is 16.

Comment: What is `notificationText`? in ViewHolder is `text`

Comment: @MeosCoder sorry it is typo. while posing question here i changed the text name so I forgot to change the text name. updated question

Comment: is the list in an activity ?? or fragment ??

Comment: @SantanuSur fragment

Comment: post your listItem in the fragment ...

Comment: @SantanuSur  please check my updated question

Comment: i asked you to post your arraylist `listItem` that you are using in fragment not the layout !!

Comment: @SantanuSur oh sorry. now please check updated question

Comment: but you used `itemList` instead of `listItem` , spelling mistake ??

Comment: @SantanuSur  it is typing mistake I put a debugger inside the constructor of the adapter where list size is 4

Comment: Why lots of typing mistake ?  and how you be sure that you `getView` not getting called?

Comment: Not related to your problem, but as you're new to droid dev, please get used to the basics: don't save a reference to the passed context. If you really need one, then save a reference to the application context instead like this: _this.mAppCtx = context.getApplicationContext()_ .

Answer (score 0):

You can try overriding the method `getItem()` from your base class.

Add this in your code,

```
@Override
    public Item getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the visibility of Listview in your layout. If it is hidden, the getView() method will not be called. Other views in the layout may hide the listview.

Try removing other views, and keeping only ListView inn layout.